# How to get 10,000 NFTs on Opensea without paying gas fees

Tags: contract-deployment, nft, opensea

When talking about NFTs, there is a core concept I'm not understanding that I hope someone can help me out with.

I can write and deploy smart contracts without a problem and I think I understand what's going on there. I understand the mint process and how to charge transaction fees to mint tokens from my contract.

What I don't know is how do people deploy smart contracts and then have 10,000 NFTs on Opensea. To do this, they'd have to mint those 10,000 tokens which would cost a fortune in gas fees so I assume they're not doing this.

So how is it that I can deploy a smart contract which has the capacity to mint 10,000 tokens and also have those viewable on platforms like Opensea?

Is there some tool, or process, or am I just not understanding how things work? Are people just using automation like Selenium to create those assets on Opensea and Opensea is then lazy minting?

Would love some help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "lazy mining" and it is supported by some of large marketplaces including Opensea. By far the best explanation of it that I have found is on [this website](https://nftschool.dev/tutorial/lazy-minting/)

Comment: I've read through this and other articles but what I'm still not getting is if the NFT isn't minted until a later point, how can it show up in an Opensea collection before being minted?

Comment: Did you work this out @ChrisTurner, i'm trying to figure this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other sources of information about NFT Lazy Minting.

1. OpenZeppelin. There's also a 45-minute video tutorial on minting NFTs.
   https://blog.openzeppelin.com/workshop-recap-building-an-nft-merkle-drop/
2. Medium. "NFT Minting vs Lazy Minting. Minting explained.
   " https://medium.com/rarible-dao/nft-minting-vs-lazy-minting-mining-explained-4330dd57a4c4